# How to send blocks of audio to be processed by synthesizer -- without discontinuities

Tags: vst, juce, synthesizer, sound-synthesis, fluidsynth

I am using the [Juce](https://www.juce.com/) framework to build a VST/AU audio plugin. The audio plugin accepts MIDI, and renders that MIDI as audio samples — by sending the MIDI messages to be processed by [FluidSynth](http://www.fluidsynth.org/) (a soundfont synthesizer).

This is almost working. MIDI messages are sent to FluidSynth correctly. Indeed, if the audio plugin tells FluidSynth to render MIDI messages directly to its audio driver — using a sine wave soundfont — we achieve a perfect result:

[image: Perfect sine wave, by sending audio direct to driver]

But I shouldn't ask FluidSynth to render directly to the audio driver. Because then the VST host won't receive any audio.

To do this properly: I need to implement a *renderer*. The VST host will ask me (44100÷512) times per second to render 512 samples of audio.

---

I tried rendering blocks of audio samples on-demand, and outputting those to the VST host's audio buffer, but this is the kind of waveform I got:

[image: Rendering blocks of audio, poorly]

Here's the same file, with markers every 512 samples (i.e. every block of audio):

[image: with markers]

**So, clearly I'm doing something wrong. I am not getting a continuous waveform.** Discontinuities are very visible between each blocks of audio that I process.

---

Here's the most important part of my code: my implementation of JUCE's [`SynthesiserVoice`](https://www.juce.com/doc/classSynthesiserVoice).

```c++
#include "SoundfontSynthVoice.h"
#include "SoundfontSynthSound.h"

SoundfontSynthVoice::SoundfontSynthVoice(const shared_ptr<fluid_synth_t> synth)
: midiNoteNumber(0),
synth(synth)
{}

bool SoundfontSynthVoice::canPlaySound(SynthesiserSound* sound) {
    return dynamic_cast<SoundfontSynthSound*> (sound) != nullptr;
}
void SoundfontSynthVoice::startNote(int midiNoteNumber, float velocity, SynthesiserSound* /*sound*/, int /*currentPitchWheelPosition*/) {
    this->midiNoteNumber = midiNoteNumber;
    fluid_synth_noteon(synth.get(), 0, midiNoteNumber, static_cast<int>(velocity * 127));
}

void SoundfontSynthVoice::stopNote (float /*velocity*/, bool /*allowTailOff*/) {
    clearCurrentNote();
    fluid_synth_noteoff(synth.get(), 0, this->midiNoteNumber);
}

void SoundfontSynthVoice::renderNextBlock (
    AudioBuffer<float>& outputBuffer,
    int startSample,
    int numSamples
    ) {
    fluid_synth_process(
        synth.get(),    // fluid_synth_t *synth //FluidSynth instance
        numSamples,     // int len //Count of audio frames to synthesize
        1,              // int nin //ignored
        nullptr,        // float **in //ignored
        outputBuffer.getNumChannels(), // int nout //Count of arrays in 'out' 
        outputBuffer.getArrayOfWritePointers() // float **out //Array of arrays to store audio to
        );
}
```

This is where each voice of the synthesizer is asked to produce the block of 512 audio samples.

The important function here is [`SynthesiserVoice::renderNextBlock()`](https://www.juce.com/doc/classSynthesiserVoice#a72ab7856c1e7651b1ce955388645a0a1), wherein I ask [`fluid_synth_process()`](http://fluidsynth.sourceforge.net/api/synth_8h.html#a1ac90e2732aa652679305f78cbd66670) to produce a block of audio samples.

---

And here's the code that tells every voice to `renderNextBlock()`: my implementation of [`AudioProcessor`](https://www.juce.com/doc/classAudioProcessor).

[`AudioProcessor::processBlock()`](https://www.juce.com/doc/classAudioProcessor#abbac77f68ba047cf60c4bc97326dcb58) is the main loop of the audio plugin. Within it, [`Synthesiser::renderNextBlock()`](https://www.juce.com/doc/classSynthesiser#a56b85b35ec0fbf296c58571ab5bc2ed8) invokes every voice's `SynthesiserVoice::renderNextBlock()`:

```c++
void LazarusAudioProcessor::processBlock (
    AudioBuffer<float>& buffer,
    MidiBuffer& midiMessages
    ) {
    jassert (!isUsingDoublePrecision());
    const int numSamples = buffer.getNumSamples();

    // Now pass any incoming midi messages to our keyboard state object, and let it
    // add messages to the buffer if the user is clicking on the on-screen keys
    keyboardState.processNextMidiBuffer (midiMessages, 0, numSamples, true);

    // and now get our synth to process these midi events and generate its output.
    synth.renderNextBlock (
        buffer,       // AudioBuffer<float> &outputAudio
        midiMessages, // const MidiBuffer &inputMidi
        0,            // int startSample
        numSamples    // int numSamples
        );

    // In case we have more outputs than inputs, we'll clear any output
    // channels that didn't contain input data, (because these aren't
    // guaranteed to be empty - they may contain garbage).
    for (int i = getTotalNumInputChannels(); i < getTotalNumOutputChannels(); ++i)
        buffer.clear (i, 0, numSamples);
}
```

---

Is there something I'm misunderstanding here? Is there some timing subtlety required to make FluidSynth give me samples that are back-to-back with the previous block of samples? Maybe an offset that I need to pass in?

Maybe FluidSynth is stateful, and has its own clock that I need to gain control of?

Is my waveform symptomatic of some well-known problem?

Source code is [here](https://github.com/Birch-san/lazarus/tree/master/Source), in case I've omitted anything important. Question posted at the time of commit [`95605`](https://github.com/Birch-san/lazarus/tree/95605fac8f23536455b42fc860b5150af579cc67/Source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote the final paragraph, I realised:

`fluid_synth_process()` provides no mechanism for specifying timing information or sample offset. Yet we observe that time advances nevertheless (each block is different), so the simplest explanation is: the FluidSynth instance begins at time 0, and advances by numSamples*sampleRate seconds every time `fluid_synth_process()` is invoked.

This leads to the revelation: since `fluid_synth_process()` has side-effects upon the FluidSynth instance's timing: *it is dangerous for **multiple voices** to run this upon the same synth instance*.

I tried reducing `const int numVoices = 8;` to `const int numVoices = 1;`. So only one agent would invoke `fluid_synth_process()` per block.

**This fixed the problem; it produced a perfect waveform**, and revealed the source of the discontinuity.

So, I'm left now with a much easier problem of "what's the best way to synthesize a plurality of voices in FluidSynth". This is a much nicer problem to have. That's outside of the scope of this question, and I'll investigate it separately. Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** fixed the multiple voices. I did this by making `SynthesiserVoice::renderNextBlock()` a no-op, and moving its `fluid_synth_process()` into `AudioProcessor::processBlock()` instead — because it should be invoked once per *block* (not once per voice per block).

Comment: Nice job. :) In fact, it is a bit surprising that FluidSynth is this heavy stateless. Does it perform much of a filtering with delays?

Comment: @bipll thanks. :) I'm not sure I understand your question. are you asking whether fluidsynth can render audio quickly enough to fill the buffer? certainly it can render 512 samples 44100 times per second; the audio sounds great. or are you asking if it can apply filters quickly enough to fill the buffer? I haven't tried out chorus and reverb yet. or are you asking whether it has a "delay" filter? I think it does not. are you asking whether the synthesis is low-latency? I guess the only latency that matters is "how quickly can it process midiNoteOn". I haven't measured that latency, though.

Comment: `s/stateless/stateful/` >_<. I'm just curious that fluid_synth_process does not even have a startSample argument and merely returns the wavedata sequentially block by block. This probably has something to do with its inner filters that use delays.

Comment: "what's the best way to synthesize a plurality of voices in FluidSynth" IIRC Csound solves this last issue by allowing one to instantiate multiple fluidEngines.  http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/fluidEngine.html